# Converting varchar pence to decimal pounds and pence

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, casting

I have a field varchar(100) which contains pence as digits, all 35 characters long and possibly with a leading -ve. I need to return this as pounds and pence, per the second and third fields below.

I get differing results from

```
SELECT
   [Tax1_156_PaymentNotSubj]
  ,CAST(LEFT([Tax1_156_PaymentNotSubj],33) + '.' + RIGHT([Tax1_156_PaymentNotSubj],2) AS decimal(35,2)) AS NegCastDecs
  ,CONVERT(decimal(35,2), LEFT([Tax1_156_PaymentNotSubj],33) + '.' + RIGHT([Tax1_156_PaymentNotSubj],2)) AS NegConvDecs
  ,CAST((CAST([Tax1_156_PaymentNotSubj] AS integer)) / 10 AS decimal(35,2)) AS NegCastIntDecs
```

[image: Results]

What am I missing in the final, double cast field, and which is the best method to use?

Comment: wtf!! is that Tax1_156_PaymentNotSubj supposed to be!!

Comment: `cast('-000000000576235' as money) / 100` ?

Comment: That's the UK Tax Office for you ;) They want to be prepared for all eventualities!

Comment: I don't want to display money symbols or thousands separators, just the amounts; also, money is deprecated, as it is not precise.

Comment: I generally don't use the money datatype because it has some limitations and prefer to use numeric instead. That being said the money datatype is neither deprecated nor imprecise. It alive and well and as always IS a precise number. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179882.aspx

Comment: What @SeanLange said is true (and I agree about his preference). You may be thinking of `float`?

Comment: Well, no - I was referring to a conversation here a few years ago. Certainly money does round (bankers' rounding?), and in this particular instance that would not be a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Casting to an int will remove decimal positions. This is not a problem on its own, as you are not dividing the number before casting. However, SQL Server will keep the arithmetic integer-based if both numbers involved are integer-typed. This can be seen in a simple select statement:

```
select 7/2
```

The integer result of 3 is the closest integer-based result. In your case, there are two corrections needed in your third line double cast:

```
,CAST((CAST([Tax1_156_PaymentNotSubj] AS integer)) / 100.0 AS decimal(35,2)) AS NegCastIntDecs
```

Note that the / 10 was increased to 100 to get the proper decimal placement, but also that the number constant has a decimal as well. This constant alteration tells the SQL engine to treat the number as a decimal value itself, and return a decimal result. The same can be seen, by example, in the following statements:

```
select 7.0/2
select 7/2.0
select 7.0/2.0
```

All of which return the same 3.5000... result. If both numeric values in an arithmetic operation are ints, then an int will result. If at least one is decimal, then a decimal will result.

EDIT: As a side note, this makes the second cast redundant.

Comment: Well that's interesting! I didn't realise that just adding ".0" to the divisor would make all the difference. (The "/ 10" was my typo.)